# Python Document Requests

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, webserver

I requested a document from a web page using a socket and it returns error 400 Bad requests. what can i do? Here is the code;

```
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect(('www.py4e.org',80))

cmd='GET https://www.py4e.org/lectures3/Pythonlearn-11-Regex-Handout.txt         HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n'.encode()

#headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:63.0)    Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0'}

s.send(cmd)
while True:
    data=s.recv(512)
    if len(data)<1: break

print(data.decode(),end='')

s.close()
```

This is the output i got:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 17 Oct 2018 20:50:29 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 226
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br    />
</p>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to retrieve some file from a web server, I recommend using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). Just install the module using `pip install requests` and use it like this

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.py4e.org/lectures3/Pythonlearn-11-Regex-Handout.txt'
response = request.get(url)
print(response.content)
```

Unfortunately, the SSL certificate from the given hostname is not valid. That is why we either cannot retrieve the document or [deactivate](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) the SSL verification, which I do not recommend: `response = request.get(url, verify=False)`